# Youtube causes all browsers to drop internet connectivity

Tags: networking, router, browser

I am running a Windows xp SP3. I currently have the exact same symptoms as this user here. [Youtube breaks my internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/114544/youtube-breaks-my-internet-connection), however the solution was related wireless headphones. I find that when I use youtube the internet drops and I am unable to use any browser to view a website. To fix the problem I have to restart my machine.However I am still able to ping or tracert websites.

I have wireless headphones next to my router however my desktop is connected to the router via an Ethernet cable. I have tried moving my wireless base away from the router however as I live in small apartment I can't move it very far.

So my question is 1.Can wireless affect Ethernet transmissions(I doubt it but I want to be sure).

2.Does anyone know of any other possible solutions to this problem.