# Youtube & Network - sometime jumping in videos stop loading and cannot connect to internet unless reboot

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, video, youtube

Declare, not a duplicate of this since I don't use wireless: [Youtube breaks my internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/114544/youtube-breaks-my-internet-connection)

I use Firefox. Sometimes watching Youtube videos, I jump from my position to a not yet loaded position and **sometimes** it freezes there in a black screen with spinning icon and **sometimes** does not recover and cut my internet connection, symptoms below:

- only Flash videos cut my connections
- can still see images in seek bar
- if load any page onwards, it would show "Connected to site xxx" the first time, second time shows "Connecting to xxx"
- connection icon still display connected in Windows 7
- computers using same router can still use internet
- cannot even connect to local XAMPP server: `localhost`
- a reboot is required to connect again and not disable LAN connection and re-enable
- all browser doesn't connect but does not affect downloading torrents
- only watching youtube videos cut my connection

Please inform me so that I could provide more useful info.

Comment: So, you're saying when you skip forward during video playback, you can then not use any other website? Does this only occur when video is playing via YouTube or when via Windows Media Player or VideoJug or some such?

Comment: don't know those, but html5 player didn't freeze me yet

Comment: This seems like it *could* be the plugin (although not certain)... Does this issue occur in all browsers?

Comment: ...i ... didn't check

Comment: Check, come back and [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/646486/edit) with all the answers to my questions as it may help others too.